# How to pass updated list to controller?

Tags: c#, html, web, asp.net-core

I'm in the middle of developing a Skills feature in my project And I'm trying to figure out how to do the next thing, I will first describe how the system is built so far:

There is a selectsize text window that allows you to select several skills together, after you select a link, it inserts it below the selection window and asks you what level of your chosen skill.

It can be added and deleted, but it slightly complicates me because I can not find a way to transfer all the selected skills and also selected their level to the controller.

I just want to know in Controller what only the selected skills and their level, that's my code so far built:

List type:

```
        public class SkillDetails
        {
            public uint SkillID { get; set; }
            public Levels Level { get; set; }
            public SkillDetails(uint id, Levels level) =>
                (SkillID, Level) = (id, level);
        }
```

List definition:

```
      public IList<Skill.SkillDetails> Skills { get; set; }
```

Javascript - On select event:
Skills[0].SkillID is just a test and it didn't work and it crashes the website.

```
        $eventSelect.on("select2:select", function (e)
        {
            console.log("select: ", e);
            var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + e.params.data.id + "\"/>");
            var fType = $('<div class="input-group mb-2"><span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">' + e.params.data.text + '</span ></span ><input type="hidden" name="Skills[0].SkillID" value="' + e.params.data.id + '"/><select class="form-control" name="TEST"><option value="0">None</option><option value="1">Know</option><option value="2">Understand</option><option value="3">Master</option></select></div>');
            fieldWrapper.append(fType);
            $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
        });
```

Javascript - On un-select event:
Here whats happen when delete skill selected from selectsize.

```
        $eventSelect.on("select2:unselect", function (e)
        {
            console.log("unselect: ", e);
            $( "#field" + e.params.data.id).remove();
        });
```

HTML User interact with skills:

```
<div class="input-group mb-2">
    <span class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">' + e.params.data.text + '</span ></span > 
    <input type="hidden" name="Skills[0].SkillID" value="' + e.params.data.id + '"/>
    <select class="form-control" name="Skills[0].Level">
        <option value="0">None</option>
        <option value="1">Know</option>
        <option value="2">Understand</option>
        <option value="3">Master</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Because it is dynamic and every time a new skill is created / deleted how can an updated SkillDetails type list be transferred to the controller according to the skills I selected and entered their level?

Comment: Could you show you html?

Comment: What html code is related to what? @JamesS

Comment: How is the user interacting with this List?

Comment: I updated my question with that, it was in the javascript code. @JamesS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give each instance of a skill in `Skills` an index value then you can submit a collection of items to the controller. I have something similar in a project although not using JS/Ajax.

Add:

`<input type="hidden" name="Skills.Index" id="Skills.Index" value="0" />`

for each instance of a skill...where `0` changes to be a unique value for each instance.

Each form field per 'skill' should use this index, so...

```
<input type="text" name="Skills[0].title" id="Skills[0].title" value="[whatever]" />
<input type="text" name="Skills[0].SkillID" id="Skills[0].SkillID" value="[whatever]" />
```

and so on...

Then, in the controller you can accept `IList<Skill.SkillDetails> Skills` from your form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript code should include a way to notify the controller that the list of skills is changed.
You could achieve that using a simple Ajax call and a controller method endpoint which will update your back-end repository (the database).

You could try something like:

```
$eventSelect.on("select2:select", function (e)
{
            console.log("select: ", e);
            var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + e.params.data.id + "\"/>");
            var fType = $('<div class="input-group mb-2"><span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">' + e.params.data.text + '</span ></span ><input type="hidden" name="Skills[0].SkillID" value="' + e.params.data.id + '"/><select class="form-control" name="TEST"><option value="0">None</option><option value="1">Know</option><option value="2">Understand</option><option value="3">Master</option></select></div>');
            fieldWrapper.append(fType);
            $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);


            // This block of code will convert the content of the skill list to json 
            // and pass it back to a controller.
            var jsonSkills = JSON.stringify([js object containing the list of skills]);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/path/to/your/controller',
                data: { 
                   'skillList': jsonSkills 
                },
                success: function(msg){
                    alert('ok: ' + msg);
                }
           });
});
```

Also, about your:

> Skills[0].SkillID is just a test and it didn't work and it crashes the
>   website

That's because you are encoutering a Null Reference Exception since you are not initialising the collection in the controller.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but skills are just a step from a few steps to adding an employee to system, your code sender seems to me individually the skills I need all along with the POST. @kevinj

Comment: Can't you just update the skill list using a separate Controller endpoint which will only change that specific data in your data repository? Having a new controller method with a signature like: `UpdateSkillList(string jsonSkills, string userId)` . @Dan

Comment: This is an option that can work in editing the employee details, but what I talked about in the subject is about adding an employee. This means that the employee does not yet exist and there are steps to add and one of them so I have no where to update .. @kevinj

Comment: In that case you can use the same logic I suggested in the Submit button which goes to save and create the new employee.